# How to Zip Multiple Files in Scala without Creating a Folder When Unzipped

Tags: scala, zip

So I have a list of fileLocations. I have already downloaded the files to these fileLocations so technically, they have content already. These are just .txt files.

What my problem is, when I have multiple files that were zipped due to this code, when I unzip it in my file manager (Finder in mac), the unzipped contains a folder containing the text files. I don't want to see any folder when I unzip it. How can I fix this? Here's my code btw.

```
  def zipFiles(fileLocations: List[String], zipOutputFilename: String): Unit = {
    val a =
      for {
        fos <- managed(new FileOutputStream(zipOutputFilename))
        zos <- managed(new ZipOutputStream(fos))
      } yield {
        for {
          fileLoc <- fileLocations
        } {
          val file = new File(fileLoc)
          zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileLoc))
          val in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
          var b = in.read()
          while (b > -1) {
            zos.write(b)
            b = in.read()
          }
          in.close()
          zos.closeEntry()
        }
        zos.close()
      }
    a.map(identity).tried
    ()
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `new ZipEntry(file.getName)` instead of `new ZipEntry(fileLoc)`.

Comment: Still, it generates a folder when unzipped. Could this be a natural behavior of Mac finder?

Comment: Yes, I've unpacked the file on the command line and it won't create a folder there.